# redirect from get method to post method in spring controller

Tags: spring

I have a link retailerId after clicking the link control will go to the below controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/adminsearchowner")
public class AdminSearchOwnerController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/retailerId/{retailerId}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewRetailerInfo(
        @PathVariable("retailerId") String retailerId,
        @ModelAttribute EditRetailerLifeCycleBean editLicenseBean) {
    editLicenseBean.setSelectedIDsString(retailerId);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("editLicenseBean",editLicenseBean);
    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/auth/adminlicense/viewlicense");
    return modelAndView;
  } 
}
```

where /auth/adminlicense/viewlicense is in another controller and we have both GET and POST method for this /auth/adminlicense/viewlicense request mapping. I want to call the post method from the earlier controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth/adminlicense")
public class AdminViewLicenseController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/viewlicense", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView searchRetailerLicense(
        @ModelAttribute("editLicenseBean") EditRetailerLifeCycleBean editLicenseBean,
        HttpSession session) {
  }

@RequestMapping(value = "/viewlicense", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getLicenseDetails(
        @ModelAttribute EditRetailerLifeCycleBean lifeCycleBean,
        HttpSession session) {
  }
 }
```

but it is going to GET method. Could you tell me the solution?

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution. A redirect cannot cause a POST to be sent by the browser.

Rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try:</strike>

```
modelAndView.setViewName("forward:/auth/adminlicense/viewlicense");
```

instead of

```
modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/auth/adminlicense/viewlicense");
```

A design in which you are trying to send some data from one controller(server-side) to another(server-side) via user's browser(client-side) is probably not the best idea, anyway.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @Pisek,

There is no luck if I use forward also

Comment: I did not quite got the idea. @sotirios-delimanolis is right. Redirect will tell the browser to go somewhere else (loosing sent data) while forward will just present different view. It cannot however change the GET method to POST on the side of browser.